# Controller Not returning value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, typescript

I am trying to return a status from the controller to my ts class that the data is found in the database or it is not found. I am getting response that is empty string

> Can this be related to the response type?
>   ts

```
onChangeArchiveStatus(data) {
            var message;
            console.log(data.item.Id);
            this.agentsService.inuseAgent(data.item.Id)
                .then(response => { 
                    console.log(response);   

                    }
                });
        }
```

controller

```
[HttpGet]
[ApplicationApiAuthorize("Administrator, ContentManager")]
public IHttpActionResult InUseAgent([FromBody]long id)
{
    var agentInUse = AgentsDataService.InUseAgent(id);

    if (agentInUse == true)
    {
        return Ok();
    }else
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
}
```

Comment: 200 OK doesn't have a body by default, and you aren't setting one.  What are you expecting?

Comment: You're not actually returning anything except an HTTP status code. Try returning Ok("test") and you should a string called test come back.

Comment: I wanted to evaluate the code

Comment: @Jefferson That answer isn't informative.

Comment: I am returning a NotFound IHttpActionResult, when something is not found. Then I wanted to have a condition around that.

Comment: The `.then` method of JS promises accepts a second parameter to handle unsuccessful requests.  Look into that.